# VBA Error - Subscript out of range - Runtime Error 9

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

```
Dim LastRow As Long

With Workbooks("SampleBook").Sheets("SampleSheet")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

I have been running this code for over a month now. I had no issues. Suddenly, for the past two days, it's throwing the subscript out of range - run time error(9).

Not sure what's going on!

Your help is appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: Did you change the name of your workbook or worksheet?

Comment: Did you rename the workbook or worksheet?  Try something like, `Dim wb as workbook Dim ws as Worksheet  Set wb = Workbooks("SampleBook")  Set ws = wb.Sheets("SampleSheet")` as see if that runs.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out!! I had enabled the show file extension option in folder options. I needed to add the extension to my workbook name.  The following modification worked

With Workbooks("SampleBook.xlsm").Sheets("SampleSheet") 
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 
End With

Comment: Wasn't there a question several days ago about one computer in a network of many that required the .xlsx extension when naming a workbook in the workbooks collection? Seems this would be the answer.